# Spring Security Filter Chain request Matchers don't work properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
enter code here http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .cors(customizer -> customizer
                    .configurationSource(request -> {
                        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:3000"));
                        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                        config.setMaxAge(3600L);
                        return config;
                    }))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(customizer -> customizer
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/validate-session").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/demo").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(customizer -> customizer
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout?expired")
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
            )
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .logout(customizer -> customizer
                    .logoutUrl(LOGOUT_URL)
                    .logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            );
    return http.build();
```

I can't secure /api/v1/auth/validate-session as I permit /api/v1/auth/**. I want to make secure validate-session endpoint while the rest of the requests coming are permitted. Is there any way to override the pattern.

Comment: Swap the first two matchers, this way `validate-session` is caught first and only allowed for authenticated users. All other `auth` routes are allowed for anyone. - To explain: when a matcher matches, the according route is handled by this and only this matcher. There is no further fallthrough once the route is caught.

Comment: `/api/v1/auth/**` catches all `/api/v1/auth` routes, so `/api/v1/auth/validate-session` would never get reached, since this route is already handled by the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Slevin pointed out in the comments of your original post the Spring Security rules are applied procedural. This means that for every request the rules are evaulated top-down. Thus, you need to start with the most detailed rules and generalize to the end. E.g.:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, this.partiallyPublic).permitAll())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers(this.completelyPublic).permitAll())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
            ....

    return http.addFilterAfter(new RequestLoggingFilter(), BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class).build();
}
```

In this example I configured first URLs with this.partiallyPublicthat should be public in terms of HEAD, OPTIONS, GET type Http requests. Afterwards I grant access this.completelyPublicwhich corresponds to completely public resources. All other requests need to be authenticated